# Como montar uma SQL para mostrar conteúdo agrupado por mês?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Preciso montar uma SQL para agrupar informações por mês dentro de colunas formatadas por Bootstrap. Vamos lá:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="eventos_mes">Maio</h2>
            <p>Primeiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Segundo Evento Título</p>
            <p>Terceiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Quarto Evento Título</p>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="eventos_mes">Junho</h2>
            <p>Primeiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Segundo Evento Título</p>
            <p>Terceiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Quarto Evento Título</p>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="eventos_mes">Julho</h2>
            <p>Primeiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Segundo Evento Título</p>
            <p>Terceiro Evento Título</p>
            <p>Quarto Evento Título</p>
        </div>
        etc ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Não sei como eu poderia montar uma SQL que agrupasse estes eventos por mês separando-os com formatação Bootstrap por colunas.

Para este exemplo, considerar que existem apenas três colunas:

- ID
- Titulo
- Data (formato mysql)

Obrigado

Comment: Coloque as informações que estão na tabela no momento.

Comment: Como é a título de aprendizado @RafaelAcioly, pode considerar ID, titulo, data(formato mysql) ... todos os outros campos de cada registro eu puxo depois que eu aprender a base. Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode fazer um banco de dados, e filtrar pelo mês e com isso faça um select buscando todos os registros daquele mês, posterior é só exibir...

Answer (score 3):

A sua situação não exige nenhuma consulta em especial. A maior parte da implementação é na hora de desenhar das tabelas.

Vamos supor que você fez uma consulta bem simples, ordenada por data:

```
SELECT id, titulo, data
FROM evento
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Na hora em que desenharmos a tabela, devemos inserir uma nova linha na tabela toda vez que o mês mudar em relação ao mês anterior.

```
<?php

class Evento
{
    public $id;
    public $data;
    public $titulo;

    public function __construct($id, $data, $titulo)
    {
        $this->id     = $id;
        $this->data   = $data;
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
    }
}

$eventos = [
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-01-26'), 'Titulo #1'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-01-31'), 'Titulo #2'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-03-02'), 'Titulo #3'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-05-04'), 'Titulo #4'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-05-08'), 'Titulo #5'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-08-01'), 'Titulo #6'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-09-14'), 'Titulo #7'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-09-19'), 'Titulo #8'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-11-10'), 'Titulo #9')
];

?>

<html>
<body>
<?php

echo '<table><tr><td>' . PHP_EOL;
$mesAnterior = null;
foreach ($eventos as $evento) {
    $mesAtual = $evento->data->format('F');
    if ($mesAtual != $mesAnterior) {
         echo '</td></tr><tr><td>' . $mesAtual . '</td><td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '<p>' . $evento->titulo . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
    $mesAnterior = $mesAtual;
}
echo '</td></tr></table>' . PHP_EOL;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #1</p>
                    <p>Titulo #2</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #3</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>May</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #4</p>
                    <p>Titulo #5</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #6</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>September</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #7</p>
                    <p>Titulo #8</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>November</td>
                <td>
                    <p>Titulo #9</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caro Rodrigo, consegue me mostrar isso estrutural porque não tenho muita experiência em orientação a objetos. Aonde eu mais fiquei com dúvidas foi em **$eventos**

Comment: `$eventos` é uma lista de objetos, cada um simulando uma linha do seu banco de dados. Se você fizer a busca usando PDO ou `mysqli_query` provavelmente irá receber um array de arrays no lugar, mas a implementação é semelhante.

Comment: Caro Rodrigo, obrigado pela sua ajuda até agora. Pode dar uma olhadinha na continuação da pergunta por favor em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88090/porque-o-bootstrap-está-criando-uma-nova-coluna-para-o-segundo-título-do-mesmo-m

Comment: Complemente essa pergunta, não crie outra pergunta para isso. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY MONTH(data)");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $consulta_mes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE month(data) = month('".$row['data']."')");
        echo "Mês ".$mes;
        while($row_mes=mysql_fetch_array($consulta_mes)){
            echo "Listagem de todos os registros agrupados neste Mês";
        }
    }
```

Algo mais ou menos dessa forma, vai de você adaptar corretamente a sua realidade.

Comment: André, eu tô boiando nesta variável mês. De onde ele saiu, aonde foi declarada? Obrigado

Comment: É simbolico, você terá que fazer uma função para buscar o mês e imprimir qual é o mês correspondente ao retorno do row.. Com isso você vai exibir ... Nome do Mês .... registro 1, registro 2 registro3.. etc