# Bootstrap criando uma nova coluna para o segundo título do mesmo mês?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Este script tem um objeto que retorna registros de meses diferentes. No primeiro mês existem dois registros e o PHP está criando uma nova coluna para o segundo registro desse mesmo mês.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php

class Evento
{
    public $id;
    public $data;
    public $titulo;

    public function __construct($id, $data, $titulo)
    {
        $this->id     = $id;
        $this->data   = $data;
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
    }
}

$eventos = [
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-01-26'), 'Titulo #1'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-01-31'), 'Titulo #2'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-03-02'), 'Titulo #3'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-05-04'), 'Titulo #4'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-05-08'), 'Titulo #5'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-08-01'), 'Titulo #6'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-09-14'), 'Titulo #7'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-09-19'), 'Titulo #8'),
    new Evento(1, new \DateTime('2015-11-10'), 'Titulo #9')
];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .col-md-3 {
            border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
            padding: 25px 15;
            height: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;

$mesAnterior = null;

foreach ($eventos as $evento) {

    $mesAtual = $evento->data->format('F');

    echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . PHP_EOL;

    if ($mesAtual != $mesAnterior) {

        echo $mesAtual . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;       

    }

    echo $evento->titulo . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
    $mesAnterior = $mesAtual;

    echo '</div>';

}

echo '</div></div>' . PHP_EOL;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim! Você pode fazer um contador antes do foreach() $i = 0, e dentro do if mesATual != mesAnterior .. $i++; e faz uma verificacao if($i==0) echo "nome do mês".. , porque ai no próximo array ele já pula de novo

Comment: Bom, eu formulei uma nova pergunta para resolver outra parte da questão, expliquei o que eu precisava, desenvolvi o código (não copiei), coloquei o código do exemplo e estou sendo **NEGATIVADO**. Alguém pode me explicar o que falta ou o que está sobrando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema esta na lógica do seu `foreach` e não no Bootstrap

Altere o `foreach` por este que irá funcionar:

```
foreach ($eventos as $evento) {

    $mesAtual = $evento->data->format('F');

    if (!is_null($mesAnterior) && $mesAtual != $mesAnterior){
        echo '</div>';
    }

    if ($mesAtual != $mesAnterior){
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo $mesAtual . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;       
    }

    echo $evento->titulo . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

    $mesAnterior = $mesAtual;

}
```

No seu código atual, ele esta sempre abrindo e fechando uma nova `div`

Comment: Obrigado Jeferson.